# why do I have a runtime #2 failure in C when I have enough space and there isn't many data in the array

Tags: c

I'm writing this code in C for some offline games but when I run this code, it says "runtime failure #2" and "stack around the variable has corrupted". I searched the internet and saw some answers but I think there's nothing wrong with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a[16];
    int player = 32;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++) {
        if (player+1  == i) {
            a[i] = 254;
        }
        else {
            a[i] = 32;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", a[15]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only loop until sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop runs from `0` to `sizeof(a)`, and `sizeof(a)` is the size ***in bytes*** of your array.

Each `int` is (typically) 4-bytes, and the total size of the array is 64-bytes.  So variable `i` goes from `0` to `63`.

But the valid indices of the array are only `0`-`15`, because the array was declared `[16]`.

The standard way to iterate over an array like this is:

```
#define count_of_array(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))

for (int i = 0; i < count_of_array(a); i++) { ... }
```

The `count_of_array` macro calculates the number of elements in the array by taking the total size of the array, and dividing by the size of one element.

In your example, it would be `(64 / 4) == 16`.

Comment: The size of `int` is determined by the C implementation, not by the processor. We can just say “In current common C implementation, the size of `int` is four bytes.”

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(a)` is *not* the size of `a`, but rather how many bytes `a` consumes.

`a` has 16 `ints`. The size of `int` depends on the implementation. A lot of C implementations make `int` has 4 bytes, but some implementations make `int` has 2 bytes. So `sizeof(a) == 64` or `sizeof(a) == 32`. Either way, that's not what you want.

You define `int a[16];`, so the size of `a` is 16.

So, change your `for` loop into:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing too far off the size of the array, trying to touch parts of memory that doesn't belong to your program. `sizeof(a)` returns `64` (depending on C implementation, actually), which is the total amount of bytes your `int` array is taking up.

There are good reasons for trying not to statically declare the number of iterations in a loop when iterating over an array.
For example, you might realloc memory (if you've declared the array using malloc) in order to grow or shrink the array, thus making it harder to keep track of the size of the array at any given point. Or maybe the size of the array depends on user input. Or something else altogether.

There's no good reason to avoid saying for `(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)` in this particular case, though. What I would do is declare `const int foo = 16;` and then use `foo` instead of any number, both in the array declaration and the for loop, so that if you ever need to change it, you only need to change it in one place. Else, if you really want to use `sizeof()` (maybe because one of the reasons above) you should divide the return value of `sizeof(array)` by the return value of `sizeof(type of array)`. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 30;

int main(void)
{
    int a[ARRAY_SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(int); i++)
        a[i] = 100;

    // I'd use for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) though
}
```